# Unable to retrieve the productName accordingly to what user click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am retrieving one of my column table's values and store it in a Label. After storing it in a Label, I will session the Label over to another page. However, the values i am retrieving must be according to what the user click. For example, User click the 2nd product in my webpage. So the name of the second product have to be session over to the next page.

My problem here is that I managed to retrieve the values but it is not according to what the user click. The output of my Label came out to be all the product name which is not i want it to be. Where have i gone wrong?

Here is my .cs code:

```
string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRODUCTSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT productName from Products";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Label1.Text = "";

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text += reader["productName"].ToString() + "<br/>";
    }

    reader.Close();
    myConnect.Close();
```

Comment: 1) no WHERE clause in your SQL. 2) How did set the Session and how did you retrieve the value in it

Comment: I am able to session my productName to another page successfully. It is just that I retrieved all my productName in my session-ed page which is not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting one product from your database you can change the `while` to `if`

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT productName from Products WHERE productID=@ProductID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@ProductID", productID);
...

if(reader.Read())
{
  //Label1.Text += reader["productName"].ToString();
  Label1.Text = reader["productName"].ToString();
}
```

But I think ProductID should be unique

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture the unique identifier of the product that the user selected (your primary key for example) and then add a WHERE clause to your SELECT statement that filters on that product id. Currently, your SELECT statement is retrieving the product name for all products in your table.

Comment: So i should change to this?

    string strCommandText = "SELECT productName from Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID";